# How to know if the BIOS in my Macbook Pro is running in EFI mode or BIOS emulation mode when in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, macbook-pro, ubuntu-10.10, efi

I totally replaced OSX with Linux.

In Ubuntu 10.10, how can I tell which mode the BIOS is running in?

Is it better to have it running in EFI mode?